# Cron job not running with appengine

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, cron

In appengine I have created a cron job which executes after 2 min of interval and post some data to my facebook wall.

But after every two minutes when I see logs in appengine it shows me following lines ,

```
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

And nothing is posted on my facebook wall.

But when I manually execute cron job url (by hitting directly in the browser) , the application posts something on my wall.

Here is my `app.yaml` ,

```
application: thisisreallyappname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

builtins:
- remote_api: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

libraries:
- name: django
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine.deferred.handler.application
  login: admin

- url: /_ah/stats/.*
  script: djangoappengine.appstats.application

- url: /media/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/media
  expiration: '0'

- url: /static/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/static/admin
  expiration: '0'

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: '0'

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine.main.application
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^crona/$', 'testapp.views.crona', name='crona'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And here is view ,

```
def crona(request):
   logging.info("hello")
   croned=CronEntries.objects.all().order_by('posted_datetime')[0]

   if croned.email_id=='n*******@gmail.com':
      try:
         access_token="##############################################################"
         graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
         graph.put_object("me", "feed", message=croned.status_cron)
         croned.delete()
      except Exception as e:
         logging.info(e)
      else:
         return HttpResponse("ok")
```

Here is cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: post on fb
  url: /crona
  schedule: every 2 minutes
```

Comment: Where is your cron.yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url handler `url(r'^crona/$', ...` requires a trailing slash, which your cron url omits.  Even if you set up your app to append a trailing slash, you don't want to do this with cron or taskqueue, because you want them to return a `200`, not a `301`.

Comment: Thanks , Can you please explain this little more ?

Comment: Sure.  The `$` sign in `url(r'^crona/$'...` means that the `/` is the last character in the url. `/crona` does not match.  `/crona/` does.  The solution is to either add the trailing slash to the cron job url: `url: /crona/` or delete the dollar sign and slash from the url handler: `url(r'^crona'...`